# Exception Handling with requests_futures in python

Tags: python, threadpool, python-requests

I am trying to use requests_futures (https://github.com/ross/requests-futures) for asynchronous requests which seems to work fine. The only problem is, it doesn't throw any exceptions for me (i.e. TimeOut Exception). The code I used is:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession

session = FuturesSession(executor=ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))

def callback(sess, resp):
    # Print the ip address in callback
    print 'IP', resp.text

proxy = {'http': 'http://176.194.189.57:8080'}

try:
    future = session.get('http://api.ipify.org', background_callback=callback, timeout=5, proxies=proxy)
except Exception as e:
    print "Error %s" % e

#  future2 = session.get('http://api.ipify.org', background_callback=callback, timeout=5)
```

The first `session.get()` should throw an Exception as it isn't a valid proxy.

Answer (score 3):

For the exception to be raised, you have to check the `result()` method of the `future` object you just created.